# Frame Layout is Going Behind the Bottom Navigation Bar?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a frame layout in the activity. I have put an action bar and bottom navigation bar in the activity, but the problem is the frame layout is going behind the bottom navigation bar, and it's also not scrolling. I want the frame layout to always remain above the bottom navigation bar.

I have tried giving the bottom navigation drawer a fixed height of "56dp", and layout_margin Bottom="56dp". It works fine, But I don't think it is a good solution, because in some cases, I want to hide the bottom navigation bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fafafa"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".Activities.Dashboard">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="#ff2729c3"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/navigation_icon"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/app_logo" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:fontFamily="cursive"
                    android:text="LootBox"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/pin_posts" />

                <include
                    layout="@layout/notification_icon_count_badge"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ff9800" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_dashboard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


                <include layout="@layout/bottom_nav" />

                <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
                    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"
                    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
                    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:menu="@menu/my_menu">

                </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

            </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

// Bottom Navigation Bar Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavi"
        android:background="#ff9800"></View>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/botto_nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/botto_nav_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the frame layout to remain below the toolbar and above the bottom navigation bar.

But what happens, is the frame layout is below the toolbar, but the frame layout is behind the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: how about moving your separate layout code to your main layout instead of including it?

Comment: please change the layout position.make it first a navigation bar than second a frame layout

Comment: fragment_container_dashboard.bringToFront(); maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
          <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/nav" />


          <include android:id="@+id/nav" 
                layout="@layout/bottom_nav" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to wrap the wrap the bottom navigation Layout you included in a LinearLayout and then wrap the FrameLayout and the new layout containing the bottom navigation bar in a relative layout then position the frame layout above the bottom navigation bar layout such that:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" 
            android:layout_above="@id/bnve"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bnve"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include layout="@layout/bottom_nav" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Then Where I will put my drawer layout?

Comment: The drawer layout remains unchanged just wrap the frame layout and the bottom bar inside a relative layout like I have done and put that relative layout under your drawer layout

Answer (score 0):

try to place this include tag  above Framelayout like

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <include layout="@layout/bottom_nav" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_dashboard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late answer.. Can you try this ?

```
<include        
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/bottom_nav" />
```